# Comparing two rows in a single 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to compare two rows that are in different order from a 2D array, and store elements that are the same from both rows. Here's an example of what I have produced:

```
String[] row1 = new String[10];
String[] row2 = new String[10];
String[][] fruit = {{"apple", "banana", "kiwi"},{"kiwi", "oranges", "grapes"}};

for (int i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++ ) {
    for (int j = 0; j < fruit[i].length; j++){
            if(fruit[0][j].equals(fruit[1][j])) {
                row1[j] = fruit[0][j];
                row2[j] = fruit[1][j];

                System.out.println("Match found");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Not found"); 
            }
    }   
}
System.out.println("row1");
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(row1));
System.out.println("row2");
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(row2));
```

I want the row1[] and row2[] to store the elements that are the same (which is kiwi in this example). However, the problem is .equals function only detects matching patterns. The example above only prints out nulls from row1 and row2.

It should really print out:

```
row1
[kiwi]
row2
[kiwi]
```

Note: I don't want to declare... `String check = "kiwi";` because the user can enter anything in the 2D array.

Any suggestions? I feel I am getting close. I saw a similar example of someone using .equals and that worked, but it was only for single arrays.

Comment: Why do you want to store two different arrays with the same values?

Comment: Same as in same exact String and same exact index?

Comment: @Mason I need to store them to build some form of SQL clauses which I will use them later.

Comment: @MohammadS. Same exact String, the order in both rows can be anywhere.

Comment: If you say you need them I will believe you, but they will always contain the same data. You could just copy one of the arrays into another later on in the processing.

Comment: Yeah, I will consider that idea. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limits of your for-loops have been messed up, as well as the array elements that you accessed for comparison. I guess you wanted something like this...

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class RowCompare
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[] row1 = new String[10];
        String[] row2 = new String[10];
        String[][] fruit = {{"apple", "banana", "kiwi"},{"kiwi", "oranges", "grapes"}};

        for (int i = 0; i < fruit[0].length; i++ ) {
            for (int j = 0; j < fruit[1].length; j++){
                    if(fruit[0][i].equals(fruit[1][j])) {
                        row1[i] = fruit[0][i];
                        row2[j] = fruit[1][j];

                        System.out.println("Match found");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Not found");
                    }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("row1");
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(row1));
        System.out.println("row2");
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(row2));
    }
}
```

But you should probably describe what you want to do with the results. These fixed-size result arrays (String[10]) look dubious, and the currently sketched code can not easily be generalized for MORE than 2 rows. There is probably a MUCH more elegant solution using `Set`s and `List`s ....

Comment: Hey, I had something like that earlier, but at the time I had fruit[0][i].length And knew what I did was wrong. Thanks btw, I just hate 2D arrays and still trying to get used to it.

Answer (score 2):

You're logic is slightly wrong in your loop.

If you look you are comparing

```
 fruit[0][0].equals(fruit[1][0])
```

then

```
 fruit[0][1].equals(fruit[1][1])
```

change if statement to

```
if(fruit[0][i].equals(fruit[1][j])) {
```

Comment: There is also one other thing wrong with when he assigns the variables to the new array output array.  |=^]

Comment: Yeah I realised that problem when I was testing it using results from row1 and row2. Thanks.

Comment: @MohammadS. I saw that, but didn't know if was on purpose or not. I was even half way through my edit to point it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is very uneffective since you don't take advantage of the optimization algorythms like hashing:

You should use a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) or a HashMap to find fastly if an element is contained.

In addition collections have ready methods like [retainAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29) to keep only the existing elements (HashSet implements Collection so it's a good candidate for your needs)

> retainAll: Retains only the elements in this collection that are contained in the
>   specified collection (optional operation)

```
HashSet row1 = new HashSet();
row1.add("Kiwi");
...
HashSet row2 = new HashSet();
row2.add...

System.out.println( row1.retainAll(row2) );
```

Answer (score 1):

It is less confusing to put the sub-arrays into temporary (1D) arrays: `row1Temp` and `row2Temp`.

```
   import  java.util.Arrays;
/**
   <P>{@code java DoubleArrayXmpl}</P>
 **/
public class DoubleArrayXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
      String[] row1Output = new String[10];
      String[] row2Output = new String[10];

      String[][] fruit = {{"apple", "banana", "kiwi"},{"kiwi", "oranges", "grapes"}};

      String[] row1Temp = fruit[0];
      String[] row2Temp = fruit[1];

      for(int i = 0; i < row1Temp.length; i++)  {
         for(int j = 0; j < row2Temp.length; j++)  {
            if(row1Temp[i].equals(row2Temp[j])) {
                System.out.println("Match found");
               row1Output[i] = row1Temp[i];
               row2Output[j] = row2Temp[j];
            }else{
                System.out.println("Not found");
            }
         }
      }

      System.out.println("row1Output");
      System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(row1Output));
      System.out.println("row2Output");
      System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(row2Output));
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java DoubleArrayXmpl
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
Match found
Not found
Not found
row1Output
[null, null, kiwi, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
row2Output
[kiwi, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

I don't know your requirements, but It's a little odd to put these duplicate values into two different arrays, let alone leaving so many values null. How about using an `ArrayList` to store a *single* copy of the matched fruit?

```
   import  java.util.Arrays;
/**
   <P>{@code java DoubleArrayXmpl}</P>
 **/
public class DoubleArrayXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
      ArrayList<String> alMatches = new ArrayList<String>(3);

      String[][] fruit = {{"apple", "banana", "kiwi"},{"kiwi", "oranges", "grapes"}};

      String[] row1Temp = fruit[0];
      String[] row2Temp = fruit[1];

      for(int i = 0; i < row1Temp.length; i++)  {
         for(int j = 0; j < row2Temp.length; j++)  {
            if(row1Temp[i].equals(row2Temp[j])) {
                System.out.println("Match found");
                alMatches.add(row1Temp[i]);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Not found");
            }
         }
      }

      System.out.println("All matched fruits:");
      for(String s : alMatches)  {
         System.out.println(s);
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
Match found
Not found
Not found
All matched fruits:
kiwi
```

Or even better, just store the *indexes* of the matches:

```
   import  java.util.Arrays;
     import  java.util.ArrayList;
/**
   <P>{@code java DoubleArrayToMatchedIdxListXmpl}</P>
 **/
public class DoubleArrayToMatchedIdxListXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
      ArrayList<Integer> alMatchIdxsInRow1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(3);

      String[][] fruit = {{"apple", "banana", "kiwi"},{"kiwi", "oranges", "grapes"}};

      String[] row1Temp = fruit[0];
      String[] row2Temp = fruit[1];

      for(int i = 0; i < row1Temp.length; i++)  {
         for(int j = 0; j < row2Temp.length; j++)  {
            if(row1Temp[i].equals(row2Temp[j])) {
                System.out.println("Match found");
                alMatchIdxsInRow1.add(i);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Not found");
            }
         }
      }

      System.out.println("All matched fruits:");
      for(int i : alMatchIdxsInRow1)  {
         System.out.println(fruit[0][i]);
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
Match found
Not found
Not found
All matched fruits:
kiwi
```

Comment: Yeah, it would have been soo much easier if it was in 1D array.

Comment: I heard about ArrayLists, it would eliminate all the null values.

Comment: Or best of all, use a HashSet and get the intersection, as suggested in another answer.